# encoding json in jQuery call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json like this :

```
{
"One\-test": {
            "name" : "One\-test",
            "link" : "xxx"              
        },
"Two\-test": {
            "name" : "Two\-test",
            "link" : "yyy"              
        }
}
```

and in my javascript file I use a jQuery call

```
var myJson;
jQuery.getJSON('path/myJson.json', function (data) {
     myJson = data;
    });
```

Unfortunately the call doesn't succeed, in the sense that `myJson = data` is not executed (I tried to put a console message just before the statement but it is not executed) and the variable `myJson` is still undefined (I waited for the end of the call with a `$.when` statement and I printed out `myJson`). Most likely the issue could be the format of names `One\-test` and `Two\-test` (chars '\' and '-' ), because the path is correct (I'm pretty sure). I cannot change those names, then I have to think about something else. Any idea? I tried with an ajax call like this :

```
function getJson(myJson){
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "path/myJson.json",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:
          function(data) {
                 myJson = data;                
                     }
             });
         }
```

but result is still the same.

**EDIT**

If I try to execute the same code with :

```
  {
    "Onetest": {
                "name" : "One\-test",
                "link" : "xxx"              
            },
    "Twotest": {
                "name" : "Two\-test",
                "link" : "yyy"              
            }
    }
```

it succeed. This is another proof of "bad format"

Comment: Where did you define **myJson** var? You can declare it like this inside your function: `var myJson = data;`

Comment: @bcesars: Right above the call.

Comment: Try doing var myJson = JSON.parse(data);
Maybe it is returning a string?

Comment: Verify if your ajax call is going success or not, if its successful then verify your JSON, if your ajax call it self is unsuccessful then try checking error, you may need to use browser console to verify ajax call error, or you may need to write `error fuction` in your ajax call.

Comment: (Nice one updating the question to address the questions in the comments! So often people don't do that. :-) )

Comment: what is `path`? where does it point to? external domain? same domain, different folder? is it `http` or `file` protocol that you are trying to access?

Comment: @balexandre what is the difference? The path is not the problem, see my edited question.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello, Verify your JSON by placing it in http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, I've verified your JSON and it says it has invalid characters, this `\` breaking your JSON string, so replacing/removing that `\` should make it working.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello: *"balexandre what is the difference?"* It could make a big difference, but your edit suggests that it doesn't in your particular case. Basically, doing XHR on `file://` URLs doesn't work in some browsers.

Comment: Side note: You're not **sending** JSON to the server, so that `contentType` option on your `$.ajax` call is incorrect/unnecessary.

Comment: @FabrizioMorello the difference is the cross-domain issue !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I try to execute the same code with :

> ...

> it succeed. This is another proof of "bad format"

Okay, that tells us that the JSON parser being used is interpreting those `"One\-test"` strings as invalid. You could read http://json.org that way (and it appears that the http://jsonlint.com folks do, as it also rejects those strings), although [the RFC says](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7)

> Any character may be escaped.

...which argues that while pointless, the `\` before the `-` shouldn't be an error. But perhaps the RFC means any character can be escaped as a Unicode escape or similar.

**The best thing would be what you said you can't do: Fix the JSON**, removing the at-best-unnecessary-at-worst-problematic `\` before `-`.

The **next best thing** would be to do some pre-processing. You could do straight string replacement by telling jQuery *not* to try to parse the JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "path/myJson.json",
    data: {},
    dataType: "text",        // <=== Don't parse it
    success: function(data) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

then in `success` doing:

```
myJson = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\\-/g, "-"));
```

...though of course that's quite a naive replacement.

Here's a demo of that second bit:

```js
var data =
  '{' +
  '"One\-test": {' +
  '            "name" : "One\-test",' +
  '            "link" : "xxx"          ' +    
  '        },' +
  '"Two\-test": {' +
  '            "name" : "Two\-test",' +
  '            "link" : "yyy"          ' +    
  '        }' +
  '}';
var myJson = JSON.parse(data.replace(/\\-/g, "-"));
snippet.log(myJson["One-test"].name); // "One-test"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```